# Reading a dataframe from CSV and storing it for future use

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, execution-time

I am working on an automation script that sends emails, hangouts messages, text message and calls when an alert on any server arrives. To store the email-ID and unique hangouts conversation ID for every server(Total servers = 3000), I am using pandas Dataframe. I have stored all the information in a CSV file which is then loaded into the pandas Dataframe. This loading using the function `pandas.read_csv` takes about nine seconds. This CSV information is static and is just being used for different purposes using the pandas Dataframe.

```
messagemail = pd.read_csv("/home/yagyansh/hostgroups.csv")
```

CSV files looks like this:

[image]

I want a method so that this Dataframe is not required to load every time i.e ends me saving these nine seconds which are purely overhead.

Comment: you can use pickle for faster loading or can put that data in an API and call it when you need it.

Comment: Thats what databases are made for

Comment: @YashKumarAtri - That information is needed everytime the script is run. The script runs every minute using cron, so API call won't help much. Using pickle might work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @FlorianH - Well, I am going to integrate the whole process with a database eventually but currently I am in a testing phase and want to use Pandas so that I can play with the data to the fullest easily.

Comment: If the server can receive alert as post request then I will be able to send alert to. Why do not create an simple python app preloaded with sqlite running 24/7 on that server or on a docker container to send the outgoing request you want to send . So moral of the discussion is pandas is definitely not useful for such purpose.